# How to keep a global state in memory of an object?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm trying to build an application that will receive a lot of messages that may be repeated in any order, how can i instantiate a class or keep the data in memory to avoid processing the same information more than once? example:

The messages:

```
{"product": {"name": "iphone", "active": True}}
{"price": {"amount": 100}}
{"product": {"name": "iphone", "active": True}}
```

When processing the messages I need to generate an error saying that the "product was already activated", I've tried to use the `Singleton` pattern but I don't think that it will work because I'm reading the message in a loop and i didn't figure out how to store the "product" information somewhere in a global state and check if the state is `None` and `active = True`.

The loop:

```
for message in messages:
    product = Product(message)  # serialize the dict into a class, this is the first message

    # On the second loop I should get an "string" saying that the product was already activated.
```

How can I store a information in a global state?

Comment: Keep a dict of `product`s keyed with some unique ID (`name` in your schema, maybe)?`

Comment: @AKX can you give me an example?

Comment: @RafaAcioly, looks like you need an in-memory cache. Also, if you are building something out of this, then please keep in mind to expire these informations after some time else you may face memory issues if you have a decent scale and decent catalogue of products.